# Delay in search using whisker menu

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, whisker

I just upgraded to Xubuntu 20.04 and noticed the whisker menu search has a short delay before it actually starts searching, perhaps 0.3 seconds. It then has an animation where the application list moves down and shows the results. I don't care for this and would prefer an instant search and no animation.

I looked through the whisker menu settings but there's nothing there to go back to how it was before. Is there another way?

Comment: [This blog post](https://gottcode.wordpress.com/2020/04/22/whisker-menu-2-4-4-released/) suggests it has been fixed in version 2.4.4. I will try to install that and see if that is indeed the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delay is a known bug: https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16731

The main developer of the `xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin` has fixed the issue. Installing version 2.4.4 solves the problem.

I did so by adding the developer's PPA: [https://launchpad.net/~gottcode/+archive/ubuntu/gcppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Egottcode/+archive/ubuntu/gcppa)

I'm sure that version 2.4.4 will eventually find its way into the main Ubuntu repo, but I'm happy to have this extra repo for now.

The animation is intentional. Someone opened a bug but the developer does not see it as a problem and it isn't something for which there will be a separate setting: https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16593 and https://gitlab.xfce.org/panel-plugins/xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin/-/issues/20

Since the animation wasn't causing the delay I personally have no problem with it.